# Rails 5 find name of parent resource inside child resource controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there any way to identify parent resource name in case of nested resources inside nested resource controller ?

```
resources :parent do 
  resources :child
end


class ChildController
  def update
      request.parent_resource //this should return :parent (resource name)
   end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand you want to get some info from [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). I assume you want to get some info from ChildController regarding your Parent resource. If this is true, you probably should do with some query, not by checking Parent resource name.

Answer (score -1):

Logically you'd only use nested resources if Parent has_many Children. Then everything falls into place.

```
## models
    class Parent < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :children
    end

    class Child < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :parent
    end

## routes.rb
    resources :parents do 
      resources :children
    end

## controllers
    class ChildrenController
      def update
          @child = Child.find(params[:id])
          parent = @child.parent
       end
    end
```